# Boxstarter won't install on Windows 10

Tags: powershell, chocolatey, boxstarter

I'm running Windows 10 (PowerShell v5.0.10240.16384, Chocolatey latest,  and Boxstarter latest). I can't seem to get parts of boxstarter to install:

- boxstarter.winconfig
- boxstarter.bootstrapper
- boxstarter.chocolatey

It fails with messages similar to the following (the log reports the same):

```
    Exception             : System.IO.FileLoadException: The given assembly name or
                      codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131
                     047)
                        at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.Lo
                     adBinaryModule(PSModuleInfo parentModule, Boolean trySn
                     apInName, String moduleName, String fileName, Assembly 
                     assemblyToLoad, String moduleBase, SessionState ss, Imp
                     ortModuleOptions options, ManifestProcessingFlags manif
                     estProcessingFlags, String prefix, Boolean loadTypes, B
                     oolean loadFormats, Boolean& found, String shortModuleN
                     ame, Boolean disableFormatUpdates)
                        at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.Lo
                     adModuleNamedInManifest(PSModuleInfo parentModule, Modu
                     leSpecification moduleSpecification, String moduleBase,
                      Boolean searchModulePath, String prefix, SessionState 
                     ss, ImportModuleOptions options, ManifestProcessingFlag
                     s manifestProcessingFlags, Boolean loadTypesFiles, Bool
                     ean loadFormatFiles, Object privateData, Boolean& found
                     , String shortModuleName)
                        at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.Lo
                     adModuleManifest(String moduleManifestPath, ExternalScr
                     iptInfo scriptInfo, Hashtable data, Hashtable localized
                     Data, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, 
                     Version version, Version requiredVersion, Nullable`1 re
                     quiredModuleGuid, ImportModuleOptions& options, Boolean
                     & containedErrors)
                        at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.Lo
                     adModuleManifest(ExternalScriptInfo scriptInfo, Manifes
                     tProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Version versi
                     on, Version requiredVersion, Nullable`1 requiredModuleG
                     uid, ImportModuleOptions& options)
                        at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.Lo
                     adModule(PSModuleInfo parentModule, String fileName, St
                     ring moduleBase, String prefix, SessionState ss, Object
                      privateData, ImportModuleOptions& options, ManifestPro
                     cessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Boolean& found, B
                     oolean& moduleFileFound)
                        at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.Lo
                     adUsingExtensions(PSModuleInfo parentModule, String mod
                     uleName, String fileBaseName, String extension, String 
                     moduleBase, String prefix, SessionState ss, ImportModul
                     eOptions options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProce
                     ssingFlags, Boolean& found, Boolean& moduleFileFound)
                        at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
                     .ImportModule_LocallyViaName(ImportModuleOptions import
                     ModuleOptions, String name)
                        at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
                     .ProcessRecord()
                        at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.Pro
                     cessRecord()
 TargetObject          : 
 CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module],  FileLoadException
 FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comman
                     ds.ImportModuleCommand
 ErrorDetails          : 
 InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
 ScriptStackTrace      : at Install-Boxstarter, C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Bo
                     xStarter.WinConfig\tools\Setup.ps1: line 28
                     at <ScriptBlock>, C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\BoxStar
                     ter.WinConfig\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1: line 5
                     at <ScriptBlock>, C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\cho
                     colateyScriptRunner.ps1: line 42
                     at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
 PipelineIterationInfo : {}
 The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT:  0x80131047)
```

Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide the complete log of the installation?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: This is not related to having to unblock downloaded files by any chance?

Comment: Possibly related to a remote profile? see https://github.com/mwrock/boxstarter/issues/32

Comment: This problem went away. It wasn't unblocking downloaded files as it didn't work and then worked after a "choco upgrade boxstarter"